# Elements of character vector within switch statement

Tags: r

I want to make a lookup reference out of a character vector and a switch statement, but I keep getting an error. I think I'm playing by the rules. See what you think.

The way I am using the switch function is modeled below. I have a numeric vector 'a' and a character vector 'b'. The switch function will behave differently whether its first argument evaluates to a character string or a number.

In the first two switch statements, the first argument evaluates to a number. So switch will take that number and try to return the (number+1)th argument within the switch statement. So in the first example we have a[2] as the first argument which evaluates to 2, and so we're looking for the (2+1)th argument in the switch statement -- that is 5. The second example uses different indices of the numeric vector a as arguments inside the switch statement.

In the second two switch statements, the first argument is an index of the character vector b, which evaluates to a character string. When the first argument is a character string, the switch statement will look for an exactly matching string in the names of the other arguments. If it finds an exact match among the argument names, it evaluates that statement.

So looking at the third example, b[2] evaluates to the string "2" which matches exactly with the third argument.

This issue is with the fourth example. b[2] evaluates to the string "2" and SHOULD match with the string b[2], but it doesn't. It throws an error instead.

```
a <- 1:3
b <- as.character(1:3)

switch(a[2], 4, 5, 6) # returns 5
switch(a[2], a[1], a[2], a[3]) # returns 2

switch(b[2], "1"=1, "2"=2, "3"=3) # returns 2
switch(b[2], b[1]=1, b[2]=2, b[3]=3) #Error: unexpected '=' in "switch(b[2], b[1]="

#yet....
b[2] == "2" #TRUE and the third switch statement had no problem with "2"??
```

Comment: In the b[2] instances, the first argument is a character. So that character value is matched to the _names_ of elements in the second and succeeding argument(s). You need to remember that the left-hand side of pairlists are _not_ evaluated as they are parsed. Hence the unexpected `'='`. Only the RHS of pairlists are evaluated.

Comment: I was mixed up about what the equals sign was doing there. Now I understand that naming the arguments in a switch statement has the same syntax as naming the members of vectors. [This page](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#What-are-valid-names_003f) had some good supplementary info.

Comment: OMG. Somebody actually read the R-FAQ. I'm astonished. Well done, Alexander. You are one in a thousand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`b[1]=1` is literally trying to assign `1` to the first element of `b` I think, which is not going to work in this context. You want a named object passed as an argument to `switch()`, like you have in example 3.

```
switch(b[2], "1"=1, "2"=2, "3"=3)
#[1] 2
```

To construct that programmatically, you could use `do.call`:

```
do.call(switch, c(b[2], setNames(list(1,2,3), b[1:3])) )
#[1] 2
```

which is saying call `switch()` with the arguments like below, which will be the same as example 3, which works:

```
c(b[2], setNames(list(1,2,3), b[1:3]))
#[[1]]
#[1] "2"
#
#$`1`
#[1] 1
# 
#$`2`
#[1] 2
#
#$`3`
#[1] 3
```

Comment: I think the problem is that in the pairlist the "=" is not really an assignment with the same semantics as `[<-`. I think of it as choking on the fact that there is no `[=` in the pairlist construction context. `b[1]` is not a true R name, it's an expression.

Comment: Thanks, setNames did the trick. I guess its time for me to review how to make syntactically valid names out of character vectors. Thanks to @42- for your insights about what the underlying issue is. I've started reading up on the docs for ?make.names.

Comment: `as.name` or `quote` or `get` depending on the precise goal. `make.names` is confusingly ... er, "named",  as it were. It does NOT make a true R `name` or a vector of them. It makes character vectors.